# Select IDS where all values can't be found in another table

Tags: sql-server, join, select, isnull

Hey I'm pretty new to SQL and I've come up with a problem that I haven't been able to solve

I'm trying to make a query to bring up ID's that have ALL null values and are located in another table.

DB looks like:

Table 1

```
BOOK ID| User ID            
1      |   1
1      |   2
2      |   17
2      |   16
3      |   17
3      |   16
4      |   3
4      |   16
```

Table 2

```
USER ID | Name
   1    | Jeff  
   2    | Bill   
   3    | Fred
```

The desired outcome would be to bring up Book IDs 2 and 3 as both IDs only have users that cannot be found in Table 2.

Comment: Book ID=4 has a User ID=16 that doesn't exists. It doesn't matter?

Comment: @McNets Book ID 4 also has user ID 3, which is in table 2, so that exludes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the sentence is quite clear, using a left join to get null USER_ID's and returning those where count = 0;

```
SELECT
    BOOK_ID, COUNT(USERS.USER_ID) AS USERS
FROM
    BOOKS
LEFT JOIN 
    USERS
    ON USERS.USER_ID = BOOKS.USER_ID
GROUP BY
    BOOK_ID
HAVING COUNT(USERS.USER_ID) = 0;
```

> ```
> BOOK_ID | USERS
> ------: | ----:
>       2 |     0
>       3 |     0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7f6c23fcfc83f07859ef33a7d46715a8)*

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks mate.

Answer (score -2):

```
select a.bookid
from table1 a left join table2 b on a.userid = b.userid
group by a.bookid
having count(b.userid) = 0
```

Comment: Please see [answer]. Code-only (and unformatted) posts are unlikely to be upvoted.